# PHP日本語文字Encoding

Tags: php

Functionは下記の通りにですが

```
function pageContent(String $url): \DOMDocument
        {
            $html = cache()->rememberForever($url, function () use ($url) {
                return file_get_contents($url);
            });
            $parser = new \DOMDocument();
            libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

            $parser->loadHTML($html = mb_convert_encoding($html, "SJIS", "UTF-8"));

            return $parser;
        }
```

Functionに`mb_convert_encoding($html, "SJIS", "UTF-8")`入れましたが[こちらの](http://www.sumitomo-rd-mansion.jp/kansai/higashi_umeda/detail.cgi)ウエッブサイトでデータが読めません。ターミナルに何も表示できません。原因は何でしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これを試して：

```
$parser->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, "SJIS", "UTF-8"));
```

または：

```
echo mb_detect_encoding($html); // ???
```